# An errors in the markers - Android, eclipse

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I am getting a new errors and a warning after that for the same application!

[image]

Comment: Please provide the full description text of all errors and warnings.

Answer (score 0):

Some general advices for those warnings:

---

These errors look like you can solve them by choosing `project > clean` from the menu or simply by restarting eclipse (please try both). Also have a look at `AndroidManifest.xml`.

---

There should be lines which looks something like this:

```
<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="18" />
```

Set minSdkVersion to an API level you want to support at least. Nowadays, this is API level 8 in most cases, if you want to support very old devices, set it to 4 or something. targetSdkVersion should be set to the android version of your test device you use for development. Also, be aware you need to download the matching sdk (in this case API level 18) through `Android SDK Manager` which you can find in the `Window` menu entry of eclipse.

---

Make sure you have The correct build target set in eclipse: `right click project > properties > Android > Project Build Target` should have a correct check.

Comment: Looks like you have `targetSdkVersion` set to 4, while `minSdkVersion` is set to 8. This is not a valid setting. Set `minSdkVersion` to an API level you want to support at least. Nowadays, this is API level 8 in most cases, if you want to support very old devices, set it to 4 or something. `targetSdkVersion` should be set to the android version of your test device you use for development.